# Error when run a query to get specific fields using JPA and Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to return specific columns using Spring and JPA, to do it I created a query but it's returning me this error only when there is data on the table I'm querying

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

@Query(value = "SELECT ID FROM users", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<User> findNameAndId();
}
```

When I try to replace the column `ID` for `*` it works fine even with data in the table but I don't want retrieve all columns.

I tried query other columns so the issue is not my the `ID` column. I'm sure the column name and the query is correct because I runned it directly on SQL Developer and worked.

Comment: you have to change `List<User>` to the `List<Long>` the type of ID

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701905/springdatajpa-custom-data-mapping-with-native-query/33702191#33702191

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. You should also learn JPQL and stop using SQL for such queries.

Comment: I can not tell you how to resolve it but i know why it coming.as i was also facing same issue.

Comment: you are having "User" Entity in which you have define column name using @column annotation. As far as i know spring is not preferring to use underscore in name of column name. Definitely you have some column name difference that you  have declared and that spring is resolving.

Answer (score 0):

There are many case :

1. case sensitive
2. check if the column name that you searched has the same column name in the database
3. don't use 'as' for alias column name

Because, i faced same issue. My column in database is user_id is different that i used in spring query.

Before :
select userid from table.

After :
select user_id from table